# sql server list all similar records

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table called "People". This table has the following fields

- ID
- First-name
- Last-name
- Father-name

and other fields

I want to list all records that have similar First-name,Last-name,Father-name values
(similar not exact) what is the best way to do that?

Comment: similar to what degree?

Comment: about 90% in tow filds

Comment: Does your table have a fulltext index?

Comment: no but i can create one

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help you at the moment. It seems SQLFiddle does not have fulltext module installed and I don't have access to SSMS now to offer a solution now. I will have to test it later, in a couple of hours and then I will reply.

Comment: I am waiting Mrs   Radu Gheorghiu

Comment: I'm sorry, I wanted to try FREETEXT / FULLTEXT search, but it doesn't seem to work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use order by to order by father name or the other columns to see smilar ones